# Mongodb copy field to another array field type

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to create a migration script that able to copy from Project `assignedTo` field to Project `assignedMultiple` but inserted in an array with the users detail on it and `assignedTo` field will be null. `assignedTo` field will be deprecated since we were gonna use `assignedMultiple`.

This is my `users` table:

User:

```
{
 "username" : "usertest",
 "firstName" : "Stack",
 "lastName" : "Overflow",
 "company" : "",
 "country" : "",
 "id" : ObjectId("this_is_usertest_id")
}
```

Project:

```
{
 "name" : "Project",
 "assignedTo" : ObjectId("this_is_usertest_id"),
 "assignedMultiple" : [],
 "id" : ObjectId("someid")
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
 "name" : "Project",
 "assignedTo" : null,
 "assignedMultiple" : [{
     "username" : "usertest",
     "firstName" : "Stack",
     "lastName" : "Overflow",
     "company" : "",
     "country" : "",
     "id": ObjectId("this_is_usertest_id")
 }]
 "id" : ObjectId("someid")
}
```

This is what I have tried so far but nothing happens and giving me an error: `failed to execute a script. TypeError: db.user.findOne(...) is null` but when I try to use `print(project)` it prints the projects with data.
This one is based on this link [MongoDB : how to set a new field equal to the value of another field, for every document in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036206/mongodb-how-to-set-a-new-field-equal-to-the-value-of-another-field-for-every?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
db.project
.find().forEach(function(project)
{    
    if (project.assignedTo) {
        db.user.findOne({ where: { id: project.assignedTo } })
        .forEach(function(user) {
            var userObj = {
                "username" : user.username,
                "firstName" : user.firstName,
                "lastName" : user.lastName,
                "company" : user.company,
                "country" : user.country,
                "id" : user.id
            };
            db.getCollection('project').update( 
                {"_id" : project.id}, {$addToSet : {assignedMultiple : [...project.assignedMultiple, { "_id": project.assignedTo }]}}
            )
        });
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not based on a correct answer though. You have syntax errors. Plenty of examples there without syntax errors. Hint look for `bulkWrite()` within the page.

Comment: @NeilLunn yeap, that is also one of the reasons why I ask some help since I was stuck and I don't have any idea why is `project.assignedTo` is giving me a null when I tried to print before the if statement is returning some data from the project. :)

Comment: Your errors however are from things like `db.user.findOne({ where:` which is actually not valid. MongoDB does not have a `where`. You simply issue the fields and values you want to match ( for equality; use other operators for other things ). If you have two collections, you either "join" via `$lookup` or "iterate" though both collections. Also extremely well covered in existing answers.

Comment: No worries. I'll just check into it. I'm still learning in mongo so I don't have any idea about joining two collections yet. Thanks a lot @NeilLunn