# As of MongoDB v 4, is there a way of updating a mongodb field with the value of another field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036206/mongodb-how-to-set-a-new-field-equal-to-the-value-of-another-field-for-every) and a couple of other examples. Some have no solutions and the rest have workarounds.

My question is: As of today (May 2019), is there a way of updating a mongodb field with the value of another field. For example:

```
//Document example:
{
    _id : '1aa',
    fieldA : 0,
    fieldB : 30,
}

//update command
db.exampleDocument.update(
   { _id: { $in: ['1aa', '2bb', '3cc'] } },
   { $set: { fieldA : $[elem].fieldB } }
)
```

Where for each document I will get the value of that document's fieldA replaced by the value of that document's fieldB. Is this possible with mongoDB or mongoose, without any looping?

Comment: Still no. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11345

Comment: I guess I now have to find a workaround as I wait..